# Excel file is not opening after writing special or illegal characters programatically

Tags: c#, excel

I am using below code to get values (which include invalid characters) from SQL Table and to generate an excel file. But when I open the file it is giving error - "We have found a problem with content..."

I am not able to paste that character here.

Is there any way to write those invalid characters in excel using code and after that when I open the file, it should open properly.

```
FileInfo NewFile = new FileInfo(@"D:\pg\splchar.xls");
    using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage xlPackage = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(NewFile))
        {
            OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet worksheet1 = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test1");
            int rowId = 0;
            string str="";
            for (int i = 0; i < resultTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                rowId++;
                str=resultTable.Rows[i]["Value"].ToString();
                worksheet1.Cell(rowId, 1).Value = str;
            }


            xlPackage.Save();
        }
```

[invalid char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mfmy.png)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to open an old Excel 97-2003 file (.xls) using the `OpenXML` library? That is not going to work since the `OpenXML` library only supports files starting from Excel 2007 (.xlsx).

Comment: My Question is - is there any way to write those invalid characters in excel using code and after that when I open the file, it should open properly. I am ok with xlsx

Comment: Have you tried this without the SQL data to confirm you are generating a valid Excel file without any data? What are the invalid characters? You could always strip the invalid characters by looking at their ASCII codes...

Comment: I tried putting those characters in string variable and got same error.

Comment: for valid  characters, file is opening in each case.

Comment: What are those "invalid characters"? Could you give us some examples? I never came across any characters that "corrupt" the workbook when written inside a `CellValue`... And also, what library are you using exactly? This seems to be something built on top of `OpenXML` (as working with that looks quite different than the code you've posted). Is this EPPlus?

Comment: I am using ExcelPackage.dll also I have attached screen shot of that character in original post. I have many similar characters in DB.

Comment: _¶l in â‚¬: 4 _